# how to convert webm video to mp4 in chrome using HTMLCanvasElement MediaRecorder

Tags: canvas, video, next.js, mediarecorder

I am using **MediaRecorder** to create a video but the output video is created as a WebM format. During recording if I instead set the mimeType as `video/mp4` it works fine in Safari, but not in Chrome. Chrome says MP4 is not supported by its Mediarecorder.

I tried changing mimeType but it does not work and I also created the MP4 video directly just by renaming it as video.mp4 (from video.webm) but then it now does not open in Quicktime player.

I think I have to convert the video using some other library